# Theano force tensor elements to be value

Tags: python, theano

I have a theano tensor W. I want to force some elements of W to be 2. How do I do it? I know that theano TensorVariable does not support item assignment. Is it not possible to do this? I can not use a shared variable for it as W is derived from another theano variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "force"? Is W an input and you want some elements to be 2 regardless of the input? Is W a shared variable which gets changed in training and you want some elements not to be and keep the value 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [set_subtensor](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.set_subtensor) in theano.tensor. The example provided there should hopefully be sufficiently clear.